# What do the second set of square brackets do in a 1D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, int32

The following code works but I can't seem to find an explanation for why it does.

```
        string[] rangeBounds = tempRange.Split(':');
        char lowerBoundLetter = rangeBounds[0][0];
        char upperBoundLetter = rangeBounds[1][0];
```

The variable tempRange is a string variable which holds a range of cell IDs such 'A6:B8'. How are A6 and B8 converted to A and B characters in the following lines? What is the use of the second sqaure brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are characters arrays.
So your code first splits the incoming string (*A6:B8*) in two parts setting an array of strings (*rangeBounds[0] = "A6" rangeBounds[1] = "B8"*)

Then the line

```
char lowerBoundLetter = rangeBounds[0][0];
```

takes the first string (A6) in the *rangeBounds* array and using the second indexer takes the first character of that string (A). The second lines does the same thing but with the second string in the *rangeBounds* array

Comment: Thanks Steve appreciate the explanation!